# Подсчет строк в строке. SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Определить какие экзамены были в месяце Х (Например, в Июне)
Не знал как реализовать голова дошла до следующего:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)// Если правильно понял то звездочка перехватывает все имеющиеся значения.
FROM Exam_st// Это таблица экзаменов
WHERE Date = '2015.06.%' // Date (это столбец в котором указаны даты)
```

Прошу подскажите как исправить следующую ошибку?

> Сообщение 241, уровень 16, состояние 1, строка 1
>
> Ошибка преобразования даты или времени из символьной строки.

Comment: Видимо у меня проблемы с использование Count

Comment: ошибка в формате строки

Comment: count(*) как и count(1) просто количество выбранных записей, count никогда ничего не захватывает и ей собственно этого делать не надо. А что касается ошибки, точек в формате быть не может и % там не работает. наиболее оптимальным будет диапазон, как вам и советуют в одном из ответов (date between ...) Это конечно если у вас база правильно спроектирована и поле типа date, а не строка

Comment: @Mike про точки спасибо большое (ну поле у меня тип Date)  Но второй вариант почему то показался более удобным.

Comment: Если у вас поле типа date, то отмечайте смело галочкой вариант с between, потому как он по крайней мере будет работать по индексу (если он есть), в отличие от like, который будет приводить типы и исключать работу по индексу, что будет замедлять работу

Comment: Ну вести дальнейшую дискуссию не вижу смысла. Все же вы правы. конструкция через (Битвин) заслуживает галочки. Спасибо  за разъяснения.

Comment: В MySQL нет вычисляемых индексов, поэтому задействовать индекс на выражении DATE(Date) не получится. Если избавиться от функции DATE() и задействовать чистый столбец, можно добиться использования индекса в range-режиме, не вот что супер, но будет действительно быстрее LIKE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WHERE DATE(Date) BETWEEN '2015-06-01' AND '2015-06-31'
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Комментарии от @Mike убедили и доказали вашу теорию.

Comment: В зависимости от СУБД с этой командой могут быть проблемы. В частности, MySQL до 5.1 включительно (а возможно и более новые) очень не любил такую выборку. BETWEEN отрабатывал в разы дольше, чем `date >= '2015-06-01' and date <= '2015-06-31'`.

Comment: @Showmeyoupower А если вам кажется, что интервал сложно задавать, так это не так. первое число месяца и то сложнее :) если у вас на входе из языка программирования есть сформированная строка `2015-06-01`, то вы можете написать запрос в виде: `where date between '2015-06-01' AND last_day('2015-06-01')` так что искать самому последний день не придется

Answer (score 1):

В общем верно, только вместо знака равно, следует задействовать оператор LIKE, раз вы используете шаблон %

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
FROM Exam_st
WHERE `Date` LIKE '2015_06%'
```

Использовал знак подчеркивания _ - любой символ, так как не понятно, у вас в поле Date строка с собственным разделителем или DATE-значение. С подчеркиванием выражение будет работать с любым разделителем.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
FROM Exam_st
WHERE Date LIKE '2015-06%'                                                                              Такой вариант оказался самым оптимальным

Comment: Если в третьей строке Date c ковычками то не робит)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Date все-таки ключевое слово, лучше использовать обратные кавычки в запросе. Возможно ваша система их как-то преобразует, но в консоли mysql запрос должен выполняться корректно.

Comment: я в  Microsoft managment studio делаю ( почему то ругается на обратные кавычки. мол не допустимо.

Comment: В нем лучше наверное убрать, но вообще в SQL-диалекте MySQL принято оборачивать обратными кавычками названия столбцов и таблиц, чтобы предотвратить коллизии, если их названия совпадают с названиями ключевых слов - в противном случае анализатор иногда не может разобрать SQL-запрос.

Comment: Буду знать. Спасибо за полезную инфу.